# Convert decimal to Base-4 in bash

Tags: bash, shell, math, scripting, arithmetic-expressions

I have been using a pretty basic, and for the most part straight forward, method to converting base-10 numbers `{1..256}` to base-4 or quaternary numbers. I have been using simple division `$(($NUM/4))` to get the main result in order to get the remainders `$(($NUM%4))` and then printing the remainders in reverse to arrive at the result. I use the following `bash` script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM="$1"

main() {

local EXP1=$(($NUM/4))
local REM1=$(($NUM%4))
local EXP2=$(($EXP1/4))
local REM2=$(($EXP1%4))
local EXP3=$(($EXP2/4))
local REM3=$(($EXP2%4))
local EXP4=$(($EXP3/4))
local REM4=$(($EXP3%4))

echo "
$EXP1 remainder $REM1
$EXP2 remainder $REM2
$EXP3 remainder $REM3
$EXP4 remainder $REM4

Answer: $REM4$REM3$REM2$REM1
"
}

main
```

This script works fine for numbers 0-255 or 1-256. But beyond this(these) ranges, results become mixed and often repeated or inaccurate. This isn't so much of a problem as I don't intend to convert numbers beyond 256 or less than 0 (negative numbers [yet]).

My question is: "Is there a more simplified method to do this, possibly using `expr` or `bc`?

Comment: how about a look-up table stored in array? it is easy to create using brace expansion.. it would be simple for 0-255 than 1-256

Comment: That would work but would also defeat my needing this to be contained in a single, simple script. I am merely looking to simplify the arithmetic expressions, possibly via a recursive method rather than multiple variables using previous variable values. I'll most likely figure it out the more I play with this concept.

Comment: not sure if you understood my intention.. here's two lines of code to convert 0-255 in decimal to base4... `base4=({0..3}{0..3}{0..3}{0..3})` and `echo "${base4[34]}"`

Comment: Ah I see. Quite clever. Completely avoids using the `$(())` for the conversion and instead prints the base4 equivalent linearly according to the value used in `${base4[here]}`. I just tried this in a for loop and it was 100% accurate and very fast. Very good idea. Throw your solution in an answer and I will mark it answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a look-up table taking advantage of [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion)

```
$ echo {a..c}
a b c    
$ echo {a..c}{r..s}
ar as br bs cr cs
$ echo {0..3}{0..3}
00 01 02 03 10 11 12 13 20 21 22 23 30 31 32 33
```

and so, for 0-255 in decimal to base-4

```
$ base4=({0..3}{0..3}{0..3}{0..3})
$ echo "${base4[34]}"
0202
$ echo "${base4[255]}"
3333
```

Comment: Thanks again. The best answers are generally the simplest.

Comment: This is strongly limited and consume a lot of memory! ... Syntaxe `{}{}{}` is not scriptable without `eval`... This solution seem sexy but is very heavy.

Comment: @F.Hauri agree, this is not suitable for generic case

Comment: The solution given by Sundeep may be heavy for a lot of number crunching, but for my use-case it is sufficient. I have already scripted what I needed using this method and `eval` is not necessary.

Comment: I was under the impression that a bad habit would be using more code than is necessary for a simple task. The method I have formulated using Sundeep's idea, is less than 5 lines of code and executes in less than `0.05` seconds using the `time` command to measure speeds. Keep in mind that I have no need to convert numbers larger than `0-255` or negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

## Base 4 conversion in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
int2b4() {
    local val out num ret=\\n;
    for ((val=$1;val;val/=4)){
        out=$((val%4))$out;
    }
    printf ${2+-v} $2 %s${ret[${2+1}]} $out
}
```

Invoked with only 1 argument, this will convert to *base 4* and print the result followed by a *newline*. If a second argument is present, a variable of this name will be populated, no printing.

```
int2b4 135
2013
int2b4 12345678
233012011032

int2b4 5432 var
echo $var
1110320
```

### Detailled explanation:

- The main part is (could be written):

  ```
   out=""
   for (( val=$1 ; val > 0 ; val = val / 4 )) ;do
       out="$((val%4))$out"
       done
  ```

  We're conversion loop could be easily understood (i hope)
- `local` ensure `out val num` to be local empty variables and initialise locally `ret='\n'`
- `printf` line use some bashisms

  - `${2+-v}` is emppty if `$2` is empty and represent `-v` if not.
  - `${ret[${2+1}]}` become respectively `${ret[]}` ( or `${ret[0]}` ) and `${ret[1]}`

  So this line become

  ```
   printf "%s\n" $out
  ```

  if no second argument ($2) and

  ```
    printf -v var "%s" $out
  ```

  if second argument is `var` (Note that no newline will be appended to a populated variable, but added for terminal printing).

### Conversion back to decimal:

There is a *bashism* letting you compute with arbitrary base, under bash:

```
echo $((4#$var))
5432

echo $((4#1110320))
5432
```

### In a script:

```
for integer in {1234..1248};do
    int2b4 $integer quaternary
    backint=$((4#$quaternary))
    echo $integer $quaternary $backint
  done

1234 103102 1234
1235 103103 1235
1236 103110 1236
1237 103111 1237
1238 103112 1238
1239 103113 1239
1240 103120 1240
1241 103121 1241
1242 103122 1242
1243 103123 1243
1244 103130 1244
1245 103131 1245
1246 103132 1246
1247 103133 1247
1248 103200 1248
```

Comment: This solution is cool. A bit cryptic but cool nonetheless. I'll give it a +1.

Comment: Ok, I've added some explanations.

Comment: And modified variable name in demo script.

Comment: I understand the code, don't get me wrong. I just have to make sure my fellow admins can understand it as well if I use a similar solution in the future. It is a good solution.